# Set a default resource limit for all users with systemd cgroups

Tags: systemd, cgroups

I can set a memory limit for users like so:

```
systemctl set-property user-UID.slice MemoryHigh=24G
```

Is there a way for this to apply for all users? I would like each user to get 24G, not a total of 24G for all user processes (which I think would be the result of setting it on `user.slice` directly).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There seems no officially supported way to do that. **(This is incorrect. See the bottom)**
An officially discouraged way (because it manipulates the cgroup)
is as follows:

Make the following file as `/etc/systemd/system/user@.service.d/set-memhigh.conf`

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPost=+/root/set-memoryhigh.sh %i
```

Then make the following file as "/root/set-memoryhigh.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
exec >>/var/tmp/log.txt 2>&1 # for logging
set -x # for logging 
for d in /sys/fs/cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-$1.slice; do
  echo "+memory" >>${d}/cgroup.subtree_control
done
/bin/echo "24G" >> /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-$1.slice/memory.high
```

You can see if it works or not by running

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-${UID}.slice/memory.high
```

If "/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice" does not exist, then the unified cgroup hierarchy is not enabled. We have to enable it as https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452728/297666

Although it works, I am not sure if you like this...

**Note added on July 25:** Making the following file as `/etc/systemd/system/user-1000.slice` for **each** user (replacing 1000 by user's UID) imposes a memory limitation on that user. I verified it on systemd **237** on ubuntu 18.04 and Debian strecth with systemd **237** installed from stretch-backports:

```
[Slice]
Slice=user.slice
MemoryHigh=24G
```

The inconvenience is that we have to make the above file for **each** user. With systemd **239**, we can make the above file as `/etc/systemd/system/user-.slice.d/memory.conf` and the memory limitation is imposed on every user. But [there is a bug in systemd 239](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9578) **(this bug was corrected in 240)** and it does not work as intended. To work around the bug, make the following file as `user-0.slice` and run `systemctl enable user-0.slice`. We do **not** have to make the following file for each user.

```
[Unit]
Before=systemd-logind.service
[Slice]
Slice=user.slice
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: This looks like a decent workaround in the meantime, but I'll hold out for a more official version.

Comment: @kai I found official ways for memory limitation and added them to the my answer above. Hope it useful.

Comment: I'll test it out, but this looks like exactly what I need (except for that bug)

Comment: On Red Hat 8.1, when I set `Slice=user.slice`, I get an error like "Failed to assign slice user.slice to unit user-0.slice, ignoring: Invalid argument" in /var/log/messages