# Limit total memory usage for multiple instances of systemd service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, memory, cgroups

I'm running some .NET Core processes as systemd services under Ubuntu 16.04 (soon to be 18.04). I have a systemd configuration file (`/lib/systemd/system/myservice@.service`) that looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service %i

[Service]
Type=simple
User=myservice
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
WorkingDirectory=/home/myservice/instances/%i
ExecStart=/opt/dotnet/dotnet My.Service.dll

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I want to limit the *total* amount of RAM that *all* instances of this service can use. I don't want to limit the RAM for any individual instance to less than that, so settings like `MemoryHigh` and `MemoryMax` aren't helpful.

I know that systemd creates a cgroup for the service template, so I want to change the memory limit for that cgroup somehow.

On Ubuntu 18.04 I can manually edit `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/system-myservice.slice/memory.limit_in_bytes` and this basically does what I want (processes get killed when the total memory usage exceeds the limit), but there are some issues with this approach:

- This file doesn't always exist on boot until the service is started.
- On Ubuntu 18.04 this file gets overwritten whenever `systemctl daemon-reload` is called.
- Trying to write to the file sometimes returns `write error: Device or resource busy`

(Under Ubuntu 16.04 the limit seems to be reset whenever my service starts, so it has no effect.)

Is there some way to get systemd itself to set this value, so I don't have to fight against it? Or some other way to limit the total memory use for a group of processes? They all run as the same user, so it would be OK to limit the RAM used by that user, for example.

I even tried manually creating a cgroup (`cgcreate -t myservice:myservice -g memory:mycgroup`) and then changing `ExecStart` in the service configuration to `/usr/bin/cgexec -g memory:mycgroup /opt/dotnet/dotnet My.Service.dll` and this again sort of works, but not reliably: the memory limit I wrote to `memory.limit_in_bytes` got reset at some point and I don't know when or why.

Answer (score 5):

I finally got this working! The trick was to create my own slice and set it in the service file, like this:

```
[Service]
# Everything else as in the original question
Slice=my_service_limit.slice
```

And create a slice unit file `/lib/systemd/system/my_service_limit.slice` that looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Slice that limits memory for all my services

[Slice]
# MemoryHigh works only in "unified" cgroups mode, NOT in "hybrid" mode
MemoryHigh=500M
# MemoryMax works in "hybrid" cgroups mode, too
MemoryMax=600M
```

**Note:** be careful with the naming of the slice, as `-` is a hierarchy separator, as explained in https://systemd.io/CGROUP_DELEGATION - a very helpful page for anyone trying to configure this. You can check whether the service is really using the configured slice by looking at the output of `systemctl status myservice` - it should say:

```
  CGroup: /my_service_limit.slice/myservice@myinstance.service
```

It was not necessary to set `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1` (as per **Ryutaroh Matsumoto**'s answer) for MemoryMax to work, but it *was* necessary for MemoryHigh - even in "hybrid" mode (the default in Ubuntu 18.04) it's silently ignored.

Also worth noting that these only apply to the physical RAM used - they do *not* include swap space used. (There is a separate MemorySwapMax setting, but no MemorySwapHigh, it seems.)

Comment: Great :-).  Template service units should get put in a slice by default already. E.g. `getty@.service` will get put in `system-getty.slice` (under `system.slice`).  Might be a useful convention to follow.

Comment: They do - but if I set MemoryMax in systemd for the template service unit that sets a per-instance limit, not the total limit for all instances. If I try to set the cgroup limits manually systemd overwrites them, as my question says. A custom slice allows me to set the total limits for the group of processes using systemd.

Comment: I mean you can set the limits in `/etc/systemd/system/system-myservice.slice`, without explicitly setting `Slice=` in `myservice@.service`.  (And secondly, this keeps you inside `system.slice`, which would be desirable in most cases).

Comment: Oh, I see - in `system-myservice.slice`, not `system-myservice@.slice` ? That may work, I didn't think to try it.

Answer (score 1):

We maybe need to use "unified cgroup hierarchy" as explained at
[Unified and Legacy Control Group Hierarchies](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#Unified%20and%20Legacy%20Control%20Group%20Hierarchies)
.

To enable this feature, add
    systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1
to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`,
run `update-grub`, and reboot Linux.

`systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy` is explained in[`systemd unified cgroup hierarchy`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html#systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy).

Then added the following lines at `[Service]` section of your systemd unit file,
and run `systemctl daemon-reload`:

```
Delegate=memory
MemoryHigh=8G (if you choose 8 gigabytes as the limit)
```

Explanation of "MemoryHigh" is given at 
[`systemd.resource-control`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#MemoryHigh=bytes).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Even though it was not necessary (in my case) to enable the unified cgroup hierarchy your answer pointed me in the right direction (see my own answer).

Comment: Also, a note for anyone trying to enable unified cgroup hierarchy on Ubuntu 18.04: the file to edit may be `/etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg` or some other file depending on your installation - these files override `/etc/default/grub` - see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1569567