# cgroups v2: cgroup controllers not delegated to non-privileged users on CentOS Stream (8)

Tags: centos, systemd, cgroups, container, podman

I am currently trying to configure my more or less fresh installation of CentOS Stream (8) to delegate cgroup controllers to non-privileged users. However, I fail at this and I've searched the web for two days now but I can't find someone with the same or similar problem.

I want to run rootless containers with podman. Yet, I fail at this because a non-privileged user needs to have cgroup controller `pids`. Yet, the following command yields no result, indicating that there is no cgroup controller available:

```
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-$(id -u).slice/user@$(id -u).service/cgroup.controllers
```

As far as I understand, this command should yield in the default configuration something like this (see [docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#limiting-resources)):

```
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-$(id -u).slice/user@$(id -u).service/cgroup.controllers
memory pids
```

Of course, I already enabled cgroups v2 with `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1` in `/etc/default/grub` and rebuilt with `grub2-mkconfig`.

So, I tried the following command described at [docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#limiting-resources):

```
# mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/user@.service.d
# cat > /etc/systemd/system/user@.service.d/delegate.conf << EOF
[Service]
Delegate=cpu cpuset io memory pids
EOF
# systemctl daemon-reload
```

Finally, I rebooted, but to no avail. There are still no cgroup controllers at all for the non-privileged user.

configuration: CentOS Stream (8) up-to-date, Systemd v239

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I finally managed to solve the issue. For me, this seems somewhat related to the issue and bug described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351466/set-a-default-resource-limit-for-all-users-with-systemd-cgroups), but the solution there did not work for me without additional modifications.

In the following you can find the steps I took to get the delegation of cgroup controllers working. Thanks to [Ryutaroh Matsumoto](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/297666/ryutaroh-matsumoto) for his work and effort in the [question mentioned above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351466/set-a-default-resource-limit-for-all-users-with-systemd-cgroups) and his dive into systemd issues on GitHub. Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.

1. Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/user-0.slice` as `root` user with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Before=systemd-logind.service
[Slice]
Slice=user.slice
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/user@.service.d/delegate.conf` as `root` user with the following contents:

```
[Service]
Delegate=cpu cpuset io memory pids
```

3. Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/user-.slice.d/override.conf` as `root` user with the following contents:

```
[Slice]
Slice=user.slice

CPUAccounting=yes
MemoryAccounting=yes
IOAccounting=yes
TasksAccounting=yes
```

4. Run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and reboot the machine.
5. Check the delegated controllers for the **non-privileged** user by running the command `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-$(id -u).slice/user@$(id -u).service/cgroup.controllers`.

Comment: So, while I appreciate this isn't a hugely constructive comment, thought it's worth noting that these steps aren't working for me. I'm still only seeing "memory pids" in cgroup.controllers - running Ubuntu 20.04, with cgroups v2 enabled. The documentation around systemd is really quite poor... I can see why so many despise it.

Comment: This worked for me (minikube 1.23.2, Ubuntu 20.04.3)

Comment: It works on CentOS 8.5, CentOS Stream 8 and Rocky 8.5.

Comment: FWIW, didn't seem to work on Ubuntu 22.04. I tried different methods as well, but something seems to be blocking everything but the memory and pids controllers for unprivileged processes/slices - the user service has them all (but owned by root) but then the app slice falls back to just the two.

Comment: Worked for me just now on Ubuntu 22.04 when trying to use rootless podman.